# Coloring instance variables in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, syntax-highlighting, justcode

Is it possible to color instance (and static) variables in C# code in Visual Studio 2010, perhaps using a lightweight extension?

In following example `name` and `age` should be colored but `test` not. Of course, usages of variable highlighting is grat feature but this is something different. I want instance variables to be colored all and always. Many people use _underscores to distinguish instance variables but I prefer to use coloring.

```
public class Kid 
{
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public Kid() 
    {
        name = "N/A";
        string test = "XYZ";
    }
}
```

Comment: It blows my mind that this has never been implemented in Visual Studio. It is such a basic feature.

Comment: Note that this has been implemented in [Visual Studio 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-studio-2019-net-productivity-2/), scroll to "User Members".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible directly with Visual Studio.  However, if you install [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), you will get this option (as well as many other coloration options).

Comment: I suppose Resharper has native support for coloring. It adds some rich color options to standard VS "Fonts and Colors" dialog, i.e. you can choose from the list of code elements what style you want this code element to be. I mean Resharpe doesn't change standard dialog, but adds a lot of code elements to list of predefined code elements.

Comment: Since I have JustCode falls to install it and check it out again :-)

Comment: @Dmitry: JustCode does the same thing, btw - different options, of course, but similar concept.

Comment: Oh, my fault, sorry, I've read your message as "JustCode FOR Resharper", I thought you were talking about some colourisation plug-in for Resharper. It's 6 a.m., I've just woken up :)

Comment: Thanks. I checked and JustCode has this feature. What is missing is different color for properties (Foo) vs. instance variables (foo). But still very helpful.

Comment: Both of those cost money though.

Comment: Don't know if it has all options as this complex suits, but SemanticColorizer, answer below, is something lightweight that works in VS 2015.

Answer (score 22):

### Visual studio 2019 and newer:

You can customize the colors for each syntax classifications in `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors` and scroll to the items starting with `User Members`.

### Visual studio 2015 & 2017:

[SemanticColorizer](https://github.com/hicknhack-software/semantic-colorizer) is working for me in **Visual Studio 2015**, it is also available through ***Extensions and Updates*** in VS. You can edit colors in **Options** -> **Environment** -> **Fonts and Colors** -> **Text Editor** -> **"Semantic *****"**. Most important extension is only used for code coloring, it is not some suite with thousands of features which will clog your VS.
[image]

Comment: This also works with 2017 now. Here is the link to [Semantic Syntax Colorizer at VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer)

Answer (score 1):

This will soon be possible, though not for Visual Studio 2010 in particular. There is an open source Visual Studio extension called [Roslyn Colorizer](https://github.com/tomasr/roslyn-colorizer) which makes use of the new .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") in [Visual Studio 2015 Preview](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) to style the appearance of instance variables.

[image]

Comment: There is an extension for Visual Studio 2013 to implement this, but according to the comments it is not working? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5b1a493f-740e-4428-9fe9-65b0028380f3?SRC=VSIDE