# Visual Studio 201x: C# syntax highlighting for new object names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm very new Visual Studio and C# coding.  I'm curious if there's a way to have a different font color for new object names my code makes.  For example, in the below code, I would like to control the foreground (or maybe even background) color for *myCommand* and *myConnection* below:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "GetCustomers";
myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

I already tried looking under *Tools\Options\Environment\Fonts and Colors*; but, I couldn't find the item I was looking for.

### Edit

If there isn't a native feature to do this, is there a way to enhance VS2013 to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coloring instance variables in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574794/coloring-instance-variables-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I've just noticed this is technically a duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574794/coloring-instance-variables-in-visual-studio), but my answer isn't on that question, so I'm going to leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the color for "Identifier" in *Tools\Options\Environment\Fonts and Colors*.

Note this will change variables, but also members and member definitions, so it might be more than you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Yes, the "Identifier" color highlights much more items than I want.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame. If you look at the list, it's clear that C++ has much more fine-grained control than C# - what you want is easy to achieve in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that supplementary C# syntax highlighting for Visual Studio is NOT free.  The enhancements I was looking for can be done with the two below extensions.  Both of which I think are completely overpriced for syntax-highlighting alone; especially it's for personal/non-business use.  The first extension at least offers a discount for academic use for $50.

[Visual Assist Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/D6678A1F-C700-4532-8C5E-A799D875063D/)

and

[VS10x Editor View Enhancer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87/)