# Can I change the font color on a portion of a string?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

Can I change the color on the portion of the following string represented by `m_pwd` and `m_senior`?

```
string m_pwd = "PWD";
string m_senior = "Senior";

lblMarquee.Text = "Hi" + m_senior + "and" + m_pwd;
```

Comment: What kind of control are you using? what is lblMarquee? Just a label?

Comment: `lblMarquee` is label `m_senior` and `m_pwd` are strings

Comment: @GrantWinney I only want the two `variables` to be colored

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes, I want `m_senior` and `m_pwd` to change its font color.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel winforms doesn't support rich content. You're looking for a WPF `TextBlock`.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel: No. Strings are just strings. They do not have color.

Comment: A previous post might help you:

<span class="coloring-instance-variables">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574794/coloring-instance-variables-in-visual-studio </span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the "color" of a string, just like you can't change the color of a number or a list or any other data type that simply stores values.

What you need to do is to modify the visual representation of that data, in this case the `Label` control. Anything deriving from `Control` has an available [`ForeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

An easy way to do what you need in WinForms is to group several Labels next to each other in a `Panel`, change colors on each as desired, and then manipulate the `Panel` as a single entity as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should create several labels with different colors to create that. You can use a panel if your goal is to hide/show the labels for easier manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

The `Label` control only supports one `ForeColor` at a time. If you need to handle more than one colour simultaneously, you could set up a `FlowLayoutPanel` that flows horizontally, then include multiple `Label`s in it that are coloured as you choose. It isn't the prettiest solution on earth programmatically speaking, but I believe it should work for you.

I say use a `FlowLayoutPanel` and not a `Panel` because this will allow you to use variable-length strings without worrying about positioning.

In essence, do something like this. The Control creation, of course, would generally occur in the designer. But you see how it could work.

```
FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();

Label lblA = new Label();
lblA.Text = "Hi ";
flp.Controls.Add(lblA);

Label lblB = new Label();
lblB.Text = m_senior;
lblB.ForeColor = Color.Red;
flp.Controls.Add(lblB);

Label lblC = new Label();
lblC.Text = " and "; // The spaces for this and "Hi " may or may not be necessary. They are in theory, but it's mostly dependent on the margins of the Labels. Just check which looks best.
flp.Controls.Add(lblC);

Label lblD = new Label();
lblD.Text = m_pwd;
lblD.ForeColor = Color.Red;
flp.Controls.Add(lblD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Matthew Haugen's answer provided above, using the flow layout panel. But with my example the creation of the labels is done dynamically. This being useful by applying any **Split** string and distinguishing between what text you want colored and what text you dont.

```
FlowLayoutPanel flowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        string m_pwd = "PWD";
        string m_senior = "Senior";

        string toBeColored = "Hi " + m_senior + " and " + m_pwd;
        string[] splitColored = toBeColored.Split(' ');

        foreach (string s in splitColored)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Text = s;
            if (s == m_pwd)
            {
                l.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (s == m_senior)
            {
                l.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            }

            flowPanel.Controls.Add(l);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(flowPanel); //was missing from earlier example
```

**Note:** to make this visually pleasing I'd recommend sizing the flow layout panel according to your application

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine but this one is for marquee purposes

```
      lbl_PWD.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lbl_senior.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        if (panel1.Right > 0)
        {
            panel1.Left = panel1.Left - 5;
        }
        else if (panel1.Right <= 0)
        {
            panel1.Left = this.Width;
        }
```