# change color of VB variables in visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm looking to change the color of variables in my `.vb` files in the editor of visual studio. I've found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2017) which shows how to change colors in the editor but I can't find the element I need to change?

I've tried to search variable but there are only c++ variables and not those for .vb files.

Does anyone knows how to change the color of variables in the editor?

Comment: The VS highlighter uses a lexer, not a parser.  A lexer can only identify lexical elements, like "identifier", "keyword", "literal", etc.  A variable is an identifier, what *type* of identifier (variable, parameter, method, namespace, etc) requires a parser.  The advantage of a lexer is that it is very fast and still works when the code is completely broken.  It is always broken when you're busy editing.  Users have created their own parser-based highlighter, have a look in the VS gallery.  Might be tough shopping for vb.net

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5574794/11683

Comment: I believe the name in the VS Fonts and Colors menu for variables is "Identifier"

Comment: @Lennart that changes all text (like functions and things like that) I basicly only want to change variable color. I'm trying to find a parser-based highlighter on the marketplace but so far have had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're looking for is "User Members - Locals" under Fonts and Colors.